# What is the meaning behind Deuteronomy 32:8-10?

Tags: hebrew-bible, deuteronomy

*When the Most High gave the nations their inheritance, when He divided the sons of man, He set the boundaries of the peoples according to the number of the sons of God. But the LORD’s portion is His people, Jacob His allotted inheritance. He found him in a desert land, in a barren, howling wilderness; He surrounded him, He instructed him, He guarded him as the apple of His eye*

I've recently been doing quite a bit of bible study. One of the terms I've researched is "Sons of God" and its usage in the old testament. The general consensus appears to be that usually when this is used it is referring to spiritual beings - Angels in heaven. Such as its usage in Job 1, Job 2.

I've read multiple different versions of Deuteronomy 32:8 most of which include the term "sons of God" - others which include "sons of Israel". Some which even reference Caanite Gods. I can't make sense of the passage using "sons of Israel" My reading of it seems to make more sense if this was talking about "sons of God" as in spiritual beings working for the most high god (Angels). The passage would then mean: That God divided mankind into groups / tribes / countries .... so that the number of groups equaled the number of angels in heaven. He then gave each Angel in heaven one of the groups of people as an inheritance they were assigned to watch over and protect. Abraham, Isaac, Jacobs blood line is then said to be the group that were given to Yahweh (the lord) as his inheritance.

Is this the correct understanding of this passage ?

Comment: In context to the scriptures "sons of Israel" is the correct translation.

Comment: Ok thanks. If this is the case can you explain the meaning of this passage. As the meaning seemed to make sense with "Sons of God" (Ben Elohim) translation. When I use the alternate "Sons of Israel" translation - for me it makes no sense. I can't understand what its saying. Why would god divide the nations according to the number of the sons of Israel ? Why is jaccob then the lords inheritence ? The two don't appear to fit together any more in my reading.

Comment: To do justice to your research, you can not ignore the work Dr Michael Heiser has made available regarding this section in Deuteronomy. I won’t answer as it would simply be a rehash of his work.  -  drmsh.com

Answer (score 1):

What is the meaning behind Deuteronomy 32:8?

In the Torah, Devarim (Deuteronomy) 32:8 states: “When the Most High gave nations their lot, when He separated the sons of man, He set up the boundaries of peoples according to the number of the children of Israel.” ( בְּהַנְחֵ֤ל עֶלְיוֹן֙ גּוֹיִ֔ם בְּהַפְרִיד֖וֹ בְּנֵ֣י אָדָ֑ם יַצֵּב֙ גְּבֻלֹ֣ת עַמִּ֔ים לְמִסְפַּ֖ר בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל)

1. Sons of Man (בְּנֵ֣י אָדָ֑ם) is the literal English translation of the Hebrew “Beni Adam”.
2. Children/Sons of Israel (בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל) is the literal English translation of the Hebrew “Beni Yisrael”.

- Regarding "Sons of God", The Hebrew term [בְּנֵ֤י הָֽאֱלֹהִים֙] 'Beni-HaElohim' used in [Genesis 6:4] refers to the Nephilim (נְּפִלִ֞ים) as "sons of the gods".

In Iyov (Job) 1:1, we see the Hebrew word “Beni Elohim” used to describe Angels not Sons/Children of God: “Now the day came about, and the angels of God came to stand beside the Lord, and the Adversary, too, came among them” (וַיְהִ֣י הַיּ֔וֹם וַיָּבֹ֙אוּ֙ בְּנֵ֣י הָֽאֱלֹהִ֔ים לְהִתְיַצֵּ֖ב עַל־יְהֹוָ֑ה וַיָּב֥וֹא גַם־הַשָּׂטָ֖ן בְּתוֹכָֽם)

Angels of the-God (בְּנֵ֣י הָֽאֱלֹהִ֔ים) in Job 1:1 a canonized verse of the Hebrew Tanakh does demonstrate the Hebrew word “Beni” (בְּנֵ֣י) represents three concepts : Sons/Children/Angels.

- Angels of God (מַלְאֲכֵ֣י אֱלֹהִ֔ים) are shown to be messengers “Malaki” from God in Genesis 28:12 to share news of blessings to Yisrael.

Judges 13:1-3 makes the distinction that the Sons/Children of Yisrael (בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל) receive God’s Word and the Angel of YHVH (מַלְאַךְ־יְהֹוָ֖ה) delivers God’s Word.

In Conclusion, We could deduce that Job 1:1 demonstrates a mistranslation of “Beni Ha-Elohim” as Angels of God (מַלְאֲכֵ֣י אֱלֹהִ֔ים) instead of “Sons of the-God”, since the Sons/Children of God (בְּנֵ֤י הָֽאֱלֹהִים֙) referenced also in Genesis 6:4 were “Nobles” who gathered to receive God’s Word instead of deliver His Word like a messenger “Malak YHVH” (Angel of the Lord) referenced in Judges 13:3.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you aware of the reason for the different translations into English ? Are their potentially multiple sources used or is this just a very weird translation ? It seems odd to me that they would translate Beni Yusrael into "Sons of God". Based on my previous research when this term was used in Job for example the Hebrew was ben "הָֽאֱלֹהִ֔ים hā-’ĕ-lō-hîm,

Comment: The Aramaic term [בַר־אֱלָהִֽין] 'Bar Elohin' used in [Daniel 3:25] is "Son - of God".

The Hebrew term [בְּנֵ֤י הָֽאֱלֹהִים֙] 'Beni-HaElohim' used in [Genesis 6:4] refers to the Nephilim (נְּפִלִ֞ים) as "sons of the gods".

Comment: Angels of God (בְּנֵ֣י הָֽאֱלֹהִ֔ים) in Job 1:1 a canonized verse of the Hebrew Tanakh does demonstrate the Hebrew word “Beni” (בְּנֵ֣י) represents three concepts : Sons/Children/Angels.

Comment: Angels of God (מַלְאֲכֵ֣י אֱלֹהִ֔ים) are shown to be messengers “Malaki” from God in Genesis 28:12 to share news of blessings to Yisrael.

Judges 13:1-3 makes the distinction that the Sons/Children of Yisrael (בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל) receive God’s Word and the Angel of YHVH (מַלְאַךְ־יְהֹוָ֖ה) delivers God’s Word.

Comment: I think I found my answer

The Masoretic (BHS) reads:
When the Most High gave to the nations their inheritance, 
When He separated the children of men, 
He set the borders of the peoples
According to the number of the children of Israel.
בהנחל עליון גוים בהפרידו בני אדם יצב גבלת עמים למספר בני ישראל

The Septuagint reads:
When the Most High divided the nations, 
when he separated the sons of Adam, 
he set the bounds of the nations 
according to the number of the angels of God.
ὅτε διεμέριζεν ὁ ὕψιστος ἔθνη ὡς διέσπειρεν υἱοὺς Αδαμ ἔστησεν ὅρια ἐθνῶν κατὰ ἀριθμὸν ἀγγέλων θεοῦ

Comment: שַׁבָּת שָׁלוֹם

Answer (score 0):

**What is the meaning behind Deuteronomy 32:8-10?**

Deuteronomy 32:8-10  (NKJV)

> 8 When the Most High divided their inheritance to the nations,  When
> He separated the sons of Adam, He set the boundaries of the peoples
> According to the number of the [a]children of Israel.  9 For the
> Lord’s portion is His people;  Jacob is the place of His inheritance.
> 10 “He found him in a desert land  And in the wasteland, a howling
> wilderness;  He encircled him, He instructed him,  He kept him as the
> [b]apple of His eye.

When in the wilderness, the Israelites were warned not to violate the boundaries of other nations, such as Moab and Ammon. Genesis 15:13-21

Deuteronomy 2:4-5  (NASB)

> 4 And command the people, saying, “You will pass through the territory
> of your brothers the sons of Esau who live in Seir; and they will be
> afraid of you. So be very careful; 5 do not [a]provoke them, for I
> will not give you any of their land, even as little as a [b]footstep
> because I have given Mount Seir to Esau as a possession.

Deuteronomy 2:18-19  (NASB)

> 18 ‘Today you shall cross over Ar, the border of Moab. 19 When you
> come opposite the sons of Ammon, do not harass them nor provoke them,
> for I will not give you any of the land of the sons of Ammon as a
> possession, because I have given it to the sons of Lot as a
> possession.’

Exodus 23:31  (NASB)

> 31 I will fix your boundary from the [a]Red Sea to the sea of the
> Philistines, and from the wilderness to the River Euphrates; for I
> will deliver the inhabitants of the land into your hand, and you will
> drive them out before you.

The Most High swore when he reserved for Abraham's descendants, the Israelites, the land in the Middle East that he had promised to Abraham's. Moses says on this:

Deuteronomy 32:8-10  (YLT)

> 8 In the Most High causing nations to inherit, In His separating sons
> of Adam -- He setteth up the borders of the peoples By the number of
> the sons of Israel. 9 For Jehovah's portion [is] His people, Jacob
> [is] the line of His inheritance.

God cares and is sensitive for their welfare when he speaks of his servants as "the pupil" of his eye, metaphorically representing their preciousness in his sight and his quickness to act on their behalf when touched by the enemy.

Deuteronomy 32:10

> 10 He findeth him in a land -- a desert, And in a void -- a howling
> wilderness, He turneth him round -- He causeth him to understand -- He
> keepeth him as the apple of His eye.